# How do i get the row count for SharePoint calendar list using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, sharepoint-addin

I want to get the row count of a list using JSOM but I am not able to get it.

Can any one help ?

The code am using is as below:

```
 function retrieveBookingDetails(BDate) {   
     var ctx = new SP.ClientContext(appWebUrl);//Get the SharePoint Context object based upon the URL
        var myList = ctx.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle("MyList");
        var query = new SP.CamlQuery();
        query.set_viewXml('<View><Where><eq><FieldRef Name=\'EventDate\'/><Value Type=\'DateTime\'IncludeTimeValue=\'FALSE\' >' + BDate + '</Value></eq>" + "</Where></View>');
        var items = myList.getItems(query);
        ctx.load(items);
        ctx.executeQueryAsync(onQuerySucceeded, onQueryFailed);
        function onQuerySucceeded() {
            retrieveItems(items);
        }
        function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {
            alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() +
                '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
        }
    function retrieveItems(items) {
        var enumerator = items.getEnumerator();      
        var count = 0;
        var count = items.get_count();           
        while (enumerator.moveNext()) {    
     //am generating HTML here
    }
}
```

Comment: Show your code?

Comment: `myList.get_itemCount();` will give you total items/rows in the list. `items.get_count()` will give you total items/rows returned by your CAML query

Comment: what if i want to display all events of single date in single row of html table in <td></td>?

Comment: It's a different question. So you better ask another question. I will try to help. :)

Comment: pl;ease check this question http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/192144/display-all-events-of-single-date-in-single-row-of-html-table-in-td-td-using

Answer (score 3):

Should you try to use the `get_count()` function for `list items` as the following

```
 var count = 0;
    var count = listItems.get_count();
```

Also check [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee548354.aspx) to Gets a value that specifies the number of list items in the list as

```
var value = myList.get_itemCount();
```

**[Update]**

Should you check a similar scenario  at [Get Current Event Count](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38976540/get-list-item-count)

Comment: am already using this but it gives me the count of items rather count of rows

Comment: sorry here i forgot to mention one thing the list is a calendar list

Comment: No problem also set your code please

Comment: now check the question i have updated that with my code

Comment: Dear @Ma6139735 are you tried myList.get_itemCount()

Comment: no i didn't tried that

Comment: that shows error as 'The property or field 'ItemCount' has not been initialized. It has not been requested or the request has not been executed. It may need to be explicitly requested.'

Comment: are you apply it on list or item variable ?, it should be on list variable that is in your case MyList

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44613/discussion-between-m-qassas-and-ma6139735).